# loading nav controller from tabbarview controller on iphone

Tags: iphone

my app is based on tabbar controller
now in my default view i am showing a viewController and lets say it has **Button A**, when user press A it should **load a my tableviewController but nothing is happening?**?

```
-(IBAction)promo:(id)sender
{
  aRoot= [[tableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"tableViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:aRoot animated:YES];

}
```

but its not loading anything no error even???

/////////// UPDATE

i did this

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    





 Promo *aPromo = [[Promo alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];//button A is deifned on this VC
 // then...
 aNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:aPromo];
// [pageOne release];
```

and in promoviewController

```
-(IBAction)promo:(id)sender
{atab= [[TableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TableViewController" bundle:nil];

 //TableViewController *atab1 = [[TableViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"TableViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];


 [self.navigationController pushViewController:atab animated:YES];



}
```

Comment: Do you use a NavigationController inside your tab? you should add one if you haven't got one. You can just drag a navigationController in IB to your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a **navigationController** to push a viewController.

Answer (score 0):

you can't add a viewcontroller to a uitabbar if you want to use the navigation controller.

Where you make your tab bar controller you have to do this:

```
MyFirstTabViewController *pageOne = [[MyFirstTabeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
// then...
UINavigationController *ncOne = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:pageOne];
[pageOne release];
```

then add `ncOne` to the tab bar instead of the view controller. :)  Then your code in the question should work (given that you're properly declaring `aRoot` in the header).

**EDIT**
Start again... choose a `view based application` call it `TabBarTest`.

Right click on classes and add three new classes. They need to be subclasses of UIViewController **or** UITableViewController. Lets say they're called `RootViewOne` `RootViewTwo` and `SecondaryViewController`.

Then open `TabBarTestViewController.m`

Uncomment the `viewDidLoad` method.

You need to now put this code in that method:

```
UITabBarController *tbc = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [NSMutableArray array];

RootViewOne *vc1 = [[RootViewOne alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *nc1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc1];
nc1.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[viewControllers addObject:nc1];
[vc1 release];

RootViewTwo *vc2 = [[RootViewTwo alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *nc2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc2];
nc2.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[viewControllers addObject:nc2];
[vc2 release];

[tbc setViewControllers:viewControllers animated:YES];

[self presentModalViewController:tbc animated:YES];
```

Now open RootViewOne.m and in `viewDidLoad` put this:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button setTitle:@"Click to move through stack" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(moveToNextView:) forEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

Now you're going to need a custom method:

```
-(void)moveToNextView:(id)selector {
  SecondaryViewController *page = [[SecondaryViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
  page.title = @"Next Page";
  page.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:page animated:YES];
  [page release];
}
```

This is only basic, but you should get an understanding of the kinad process you need to go through. I typed this straight into the browser so there may be spelling mistakes... watch out if you get any errors or warnings. Hopefully this can help you with your project.

Comment: i did this - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    
    
    
    
    
    Promo *aPromo = [[Promo alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    // then...
    aNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:aPromo];
//    [pageOne release];

Comment: erm, thats not right.... are you using IB? I don't use IB unfortunately, my solution is programatic.

Comment: its ok i changed to Programmatic , but what should i write in IBAction()??

Comment: thanks but its not working for me .. just to load a new view on button tap its difficult to change whole architecture of my project , :( , i tried your way also but its not loading my tableview... hey when i tried this [self presentModalViewController:atab animated:YES];  then  can load new window but that hides all my tabbar icons , if i can unhide those then i think my work will be safe  :(  plz suggest any other method if you have thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally i solved this , i changed that VC to Navigation view Controller and then i can push the new view based on button tap,, thanks to thomas also who helped me a lot but i couldn't figure it out.